# Kendo Upload complete event return [object Object] from php file

Tags: javascript, php, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I had kendo grid with inline editing. Now I want to add an upload images to '`propertyLogo`' field. Basically, I use an editor function and call `saveUrl: "indexHex.php`, and fetch by PHP post method then convert to `base64` and store into `$imageHex` variable.

In kendo Upload `complete` event, I load the php file and pass `$imageHex` to textbox. But somehow I get *[obeject Object]* in the textbox.

Any idea how I can fetch the `$imageHex` from `indexHex.php`

[image]

[Here my sample in DOJO](https://dojo.telerik.com/eMijeQAv)

**my indexHex.php**

```js
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
 
 $file = $_FILES['fileUpload']; 
 $fileName = $_FILES['fileUpload']['name'];
 $fileTmpName = $_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'];  //directory location 
 $fileSize = $_FILES['fileUpload']['size'];
 $fileError = $_FILES['fileUpload']['error'];  //default 0 | 1 got error
 
 $path = getcwd();
 $fileDestination = $path.'/uploads/'.$fileName;                    
 move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination); 

 $data = file_get_contents($fileTmpName);
 $imageHex = base64_encode($data);
 
 echo $imageHex;
}
```

This problem a almost similar with my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56829239/kendo-grid-inline-editing-with-kendo-upload-return-an-null-result) but with different approach.

Comment: That server response doesn't seems to be a valid base64 string. Check this out: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-an-image-to-base64-encoding-in-php/ look at the *output*.

Comment: Also, you should console the variable you're trying to set to the input's value. It is probably an object with a property that contains what you really wants.

Comment: I already change and server response to base64 string. But I still couldn't fetch the `$imageHex` variable. I think I need to use success event  in kendo Upload to get server response in `indexHEx.php` but I do not know how to do.